# I came from a distant land

Tags: riddle

> Me and my dozens of friends came from a distant land.
>   You might not know most of us,
>   but you probably used some of us.
>   Some pronounce my name like a delicious pastry,
>   but in reality it sounds like something tiny.
>   Some people remember parts of me,
>   but you'll need my entirety when things starts spinning around.

Who am I?

Comment: the [tag:rhyme] tag isnt a bit ... dreamy?

Comment: Is it that bad? I tried a little but... guess I will remove it XD

Comment: how about, pastry->reality->tiny->me->entirety? XD

Comment: "me" and "tiny" have the same "e" sound but not the same entonation as the "me" is *stressed* and "ny" not . you say *ti*ny, not ti*ny*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is it

> Pi?

Me and my dozens of friends came from a distant land.
You might not know most of us,
 but you probably used some of us.

> The ancient greek alphabet has 24 letters (2 dozen). I don't know all of them, but I use a fair few characters as symbols in maths

Some pronounce my name like a delicious pastry,
 but in reality it sounds like something tiny.

> Pies are tasty! <strike>Not sure about something tiny - could be something to do with a pion?</strike> Apparently it should be pronounced with more of an 'ee' sound, like a small green pea

Some people remember parts of me,
but you'll need my entirety when things starts spinning around.

> People compete over how many digits of pi they can remember. The entire irrational number is needed for mathematical and scientific purposes, though, most of which involve circles in some manner.

Comment: Was just about to write this, the way people normally pronounce it in English speaking countries is wrong, should be with more of an 'ee' sound.

Comment: @hexomino I did not know that, thanks! Looks like I've been saying it incorrectly for years, then

Comment: Who am I? Does this mean the answer is not an object / abstract?

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst "Who am I?" is a fairly common construct in riddles used to allow the author to describe the solution from a first-person perspective. It doesn't tend to mean that the solution is a person.

Comment: @hexomino it's not wrong! That's how π is pronounced in English. Yes, in Greek (or at least in Modern Greek, I don't know about Ancient) it is pronounced like the "pi" in "pick" (not "pea")  but that's a different language. Claiming it's wrong is like expecting the word *xylophone* to be pronounced with a hard *x* just because that's how it's pronounced in Greek.

Comment: You got everything right from the pea to the competing thing. good job! Faster than expected.

Comment: @terdon Perhaps 'wrong' is a bit too harsh but instead 'different from the original intention'. In my defence, I did say 'more of an"ee" sound' rather than just 'an "ee" sound'. Also, if *xylophone* was originally pronounced with a hard 'x', I would be happy to revert to that, it sounds way better.

Comment: @hexomino sorry, native speaker of Greek and English here, so it's a subject close to my heart :) But no, all languages have loan words and their pronunciation changes. That's just part of how languages evolve. This is way off topic here ( would be a nice discussion in [ELU chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage) though, feel free to ping me) but you can't impose the original pronunciation onto a new language.

Answer (score 6):

I think its

> A clock

Me and my dozens of friends came from a distant land.

> The clock and its twelve numbers come from the land of time

You might not know most of us,

> There are a lot of types of clocks

but you probably used some of us.

> Alarm clock, stopwatch, watch, phone clock etc.

Some pronounce my name like a delicious pastry,

> Found [Bakpia Path**ok**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakpia_Pathok) and [Bier**ock**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bierock) but more likely to be [Kołacz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ko%C5%82acz)  (Kah-lec = Cer-lock))

but in reality it sounds like something tiny.

> Makes it sound like just the thing on your hand instead of a time keeper

Some people remember parts of me,

> The hands, face or numbers

but you'll need my entirety when things starts spinning around.

> You need all parts to make the clock spin

Comment: +1 Good but not quite. For one, there are dozen"s" of friends. The pastry will be well known by all without any search, Also you don't need all of me "for" spinning around, but "when" it starts spinning.

Comment: Just to make it clear, by "Good but not quite" I meant it was a nice try. The answer though is totally unrelated.